# new Angular.js 1.1.5 resource returning promise then() function error followed by another request

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-resource

I'm working with the latest Angular.js, 1.1.5 which return promise with the resource call.
What would be a correct implementation when you have multiple requests that will be followed by another one that depends on these?

```
$scope.save = function() {
    var newids = [];
    angular.forEach ($scope.template.children, function (value){
        //saves the children as a new template and returns the ID
        Template.$addNew(value).then(
            function( value ){newids.push(value);},
            function ( error ) {console.log ('error')}
        )
    });

    //updates the root template
    $scope.template.childrenIDs = newids;
    Template.$update($scope.template).then(
            function( value ){ console.log('successfully saved')},
            function ( error ) {console.log ('error')}
        )
}
```

For this I get an error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'then'

with template being the following factory returning a resource:

```
mongoAPI.
factory('Template', ['$resource', '$http', 'CONSTANTS', 'security', function($resource, $http, CONSTANTS, security) {
    var actions = {                        
        'addNew': {method:'POST'},   
    }
    var res = $resource(CONSTANTS.url, {}, actions)
    return res;
}]);
```

Answer (score 5):

### FYI

From 1.2.0 onwards `$resource` exposes a `$promise`:

```
Template.$addNew(value).$promise.then(
    function( value ){newids.push(value);},
    function ( error ) {console.log ('error')}
)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#resource$then-has-been-removed)

Answer (score 2):

Fully exposed promises are currently only avaliable in master (commit https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/05772e15fbecfdc63d4977e2e8839d8b95d6a92d).

Beginning with 1.1.3, $resource exposed the promises' `then` function via `$then` (likewise $resolved):

```
Template.$addNew(value).$then(
    function( value ){newids.push(value);},
    function ( error ) {console.log ('error')}
)
```